# :class не работает динамически

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Добрый день.
Есть такой код:
[Ссылка на гитхаб](https://github.com/Mike-Kharkov/Vue-testing/blob/8ad4e705cbc63f1fcb70860210c24153ccdf6090/src/Form.vue)

Ситуация следующая:
Я прохожу курс по Vue.js и стоит задача кастомизировать радио баттоны.
На данный момент я поставил себе за цель прикрутить к каждому баттону дополнительный класс "active" - при клике на него.
(и соответственно что бы другой элемент(радио кнопка) менял свое состояние(класс 'active') на противоположенное при необходимости.)

Был создан массив с двумя элементами(для каждой радио кнопки.)
В зависимости от состояния элемента в массиве(true или false) - я планировал включать или выключать класс "active" в каждой кнопке.

При загрузке страницы - классы в кнопках были отстроены правильно в дом дереве(исходя из состояния элементов в массиве.)

Изменить элемент массива при клике удалось.
Но мне пока что совершенно не ясно почему не изменяется класс в каждом радиобаттоне именно при клике - ведь я же подвязал зависимость класса от состояния элемента массива..?

Не понимаю что упустил из виду.
(создается впечатление что св-во :class не динамическое.
Но на сколько мне известно - это не так.)

Буду благодарен за любой конструктивный совет..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело может быть в том, что сам объект не меняется непосредственно при клике.

Вообще, с массивами не так просто поддерживать состояние [реактивности](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).
Теоретически, ситуацию должна исправлять [функция $set](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set), но на практике это срабатывает не всегда.

Гораздо лучше отслеживаются изменения в объектах, но тоже не идеально: значение, которое отслеживается, должно существовать изначально, при инициализации.

Дело может быть в другом, но этот вариант очень возможен.

Посмотрел код.

1. Свойство float меняет местами radio buttons. Я так понимаю, что это лишнее.
2. Странная логика определения нажатия на radio. Гораздо проще передавать индекс нажатого radio.
3. А собственно, массив здесь не очень нужен, достаточно хранить только итоговое значение.

Пример готового кода:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
      data(){
        return{
          form: {
            storeData: 0
          }
        }
      },
      methods:{
        clickStoreData: function(index){
         this.form.storeData = index-1
        }
      },
})
```

```css
    fieldset .wrap_radio{
        margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
        height: 30px;
        width: 200px;
        font: 400 15px/30px arial;
        color: #000;
        text-align:left;
        display: block;
    }
    fieldset .wrap_radio .radio{
        border: 3px solid #852005;
        margin: 7px 1px 5px 1px;
        border-radius:12px;
        height: 15px;
        width: 30px;
        background-color: #ff363d;
        /*float: right;*/
        cursor: pointer;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    fieldset .wrap_radio .radio.active{
        border: 3px solid #024406;
        background-color: #019163;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <fieldset id="app">
        <div class="wrap_radio">Store Data? Yes/No
            <div 
                 v-for="index in 2"
                 @click="clickStoreData(index)"
                 class="radio"
                 :class="{'active': form.storeData == index-1}"
                 >
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

Ссылка jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Nic34/eywraw8t/43540/